# Calendar holidays errors

Tags: calendar

After updating all the packages and switched to Emacs HEAD the holidays config I used to use now generate errors on Emacs start.

Config:

```lisp
  (setq
    general-holidays
    '((holiday-fixed 1 1 "New Year's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 2 14 "Valentine's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 3 8 "International Women's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 3 17 "St. Patrick's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 4 1 "April Fools' Day")
       (holiday-float 5 0 2 "Mother's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 10 31 "Halloween")
       (holiday-float 11 4 4 "Thanksgiving"))
    polish-holidays
    '((holiday-fixed  1 21 "Dzień Babci")
       (holiday-fixed  1 22 "Dzień Diadka")
       (holiday-fixed  2 22 "Ofiarowanie Pańskie (Matki Boskiej Gromnicznej)")
       (holiday-fixed  2  8 "Tłusty Czwartek")
       (holiday-fixed  2 10 "Ostatnia Sobota Karnawału")
       (holiday-fixed  2 13 "Ostatki")
       (holiday-fixed  3  1 "Narodowy Dzień Pamięci Żołnierzy Wyklętych")
       (holiday-fixed  3 10 "Dzień Mężczyzn")
       (holiday-fixed  3 20 "Początek Astronomicznej Wiosny")
       (holiday-fixed  3 25 "Zmiana czasu z zimowego na letni")
       (holiday-fixed  3 25 "Niedziela Palmowa")
       (holiday-fixed  3 29 "Wielki Czwartek")
       (holiday-fixed  3 30 "Wielki Piątek")
       (holiday-fixed  3 31 "Wielka Sobota")
       (holiday-fixed  4  2 "(bank) Poniedziałek Wielkanocny")
       (holiday-fixed  4  8 "Święto Bożego Miłosierdzia")
       (holiday-fixed  4 22 "Międzynarodowy Dzień Ziemi")
       (holiday-fixed  5  1 "(bank) Międzynarodowe Święto Pracy")
       (holiday-fixed  5  2 "Dzień Flagi Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej")
       (holiday-fixed  5  3 "(bank) Święto Konstytucji 3 Maja")
       (holiday-fixed  5 13 "Wniebowstąpienie")
       (holiday-fixed  5 20 "(bank) Zesłanie Ducha Świętego (Zielone Świątki)")
       (holiday-fixed  5 26 "Dzień Matki")
       (holiday-fixed  5 31 "(bank) Boże Ciało")
       (holiday-fixed  6  1 "Międzynarodowy Dzień Dziecka")
       (holiday-fixed  6 21 "Pierwszy Dzień Lata (najdłuższy dzień roku)")
       (holiday-fixed  6 23 "Dzień Ojca")
       (holiday-fixed  8  1 "Narodowy Dzień Pamięci Powstania Warszawskiego")
       (holiday-fixed  8 15 "(bank) Święto Wojska Polskiego")
       (holiday-fixed  8 15 "Wniebowzięcie Najświętrzej Maryi Panny")
       (holiday-fixed  8 31 "Dzień Solidarności i Wolności")
       (holiday-fixed  9 23 "Początek Astronomicznej Jesieni")
       (holiday-fixed  9 30 "Dzień Chłopaka")
       (holiday-fixed 10 14 "Dzień Nauczyciela (Dzień Edukacji Narodowej)")
       (holiday-fixed 10 28 "Zmiana czasu z letniego na zimowy")
       (holiday-fixed 11  1 "(bank) Wszystkich Świętych")
       (holiday-fixed 11  2 "Dzień Zaduszny")
       (holiday-fixed 11 11 "(bank) Narodowe Święto Niepodległości")
       (holiday-fixed 11 29 "Andrzejki")
       (holiday-fixed 12  4 "Barbórka (Dzień górnika, naftowca i gazownika)")
       (holiday-fixed 12  6 "Dzień św. Mikołaja")
       (holiday-fixed 12 21 "Początek Astronomicznej Zimy")
       (holiday-fixed 12 24 "Wigilia Bożego Narodzenia")
       (holiday-fixed 12 25 "(bank) Boże Narodzenie (1 dzień)")
       (holiday-fixed 12 26 "(bank) Boże Narodzenie (2 dzień)"))
    english-holidays
    '((holiday-fixed  3 30 "(bank) Good Friday")
       (holiday-fixed  4 10 "(bank) Good Friday (England, Wales)")
       (holiday-fixed  4 13 "(bank) Easter Monday (England, Wales)")
       (holiday-fixed  5  8 "(bank) Early May bank holiday (England, Wales)")
       (holiday-fixed  5  7 "(bank) Spring bank holiday (England, Wales)")
       (holiday-fixed  8 27 "(bank) Spring bank holiday")
       (holiday-fixed  9 31 "(bank) Summer bank holiday")
       (holiday-fixed 12 25 "(bank) Christmas Day")
       (holiday-fixed 12 28 "(bank) Boxing Day"))
    christian-holidays
    '((holiday-fixed 1 6 "Epiphany")
       (holiday-fixed 2 2 "Candlemas")
       (holiday-easter-etc -47 "Mardi Gras")
       (holiday-easter-etc 0 "Easter Day")
       (holiday-easter-etc 1 "Easter Monday")
       (holiday-easter-etc 39 "Ascension")
       (holiday-easter-etc 49 "Pentecost")
       (holiday-fixed 8 15 "Assumption")
       (holiday-fixed 11 1 "All Saints' Day")
       (holiday-fixed 11 2 "Day of the Dead")
       (holiday-fixed 11 22 "Saint Cecilia's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 12 1 "Saint Eloi's Day")
       (holiday-fixed 12 4 "Saint Barbara")
       (holiday-fixed 12 6 "Saint Nicholas Day")
       (holiday-fixed 12 25 "Christmas Day")))

  (use-package japanese-holidays)

  (setq
    holiday-local-holidays nil
    calendar-christian-all-holidays-flag t
    calendar-holidays (list
                        japanese-holidays
                        polish-holidays
                        english-holidays
                        general-holidays
                        holiday-christian-holidays
                        holiday-solar-holidays)
    calendar-week-start-day 1
    calendar-date-style 'european))
```

Errors:

```
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 3 元始祭) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 5 新年宴会) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 30 孝明天皇祭) '(10 14 1873) '(9 3 1912)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 2 11 紀元節) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 4 3 神武天皇祭) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 9 17 神嘗祭) '(10 14 1873) '(7 5 1879)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 11 3 天長節) '(10 14 1873) '(9 3 1912)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 11 23 新嘗祭) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)) (let* ((equinox (solar-equinoxes/solstices 0 displayed-year)) (m (calendar-extract-month equinox)) (d (truncate (calendar-extract-day equinox)))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed m d 春季皇霊祭) '(6 5 1878) '(7 20 1948))) (let* ((equinox (solar-equinoxes/solstices 2 displayed-year)) (m (calendar-extract-month equinox)) (d (truncate (calendar-extract-day equinox)))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed m d 秋季皇霊祭) '(6 5 1878) '(7 20 1948))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 10 17 神嘗祭) '(7 5 1879) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 30 明治天皇祭) '(9 3 1912) '(3 3 1927)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 8 31 天長節) '(9 3 1912) '(3 3 1927)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 10 31 天長節祝日) '(10 31 1913) '(3 3 1927)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 4 29 天長節) '(3 3 1927) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 11 3 明治節) '(3 3 1927) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 12 25 大正天皇祭) '(3 3 1927) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-national (japanese-holiday-substitute (nconc (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 1 元日) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 15 成人の日) '(7 20 1947) '(1 1 2000)) (let* ((equinox (solar-equinoxes/solstices 0 displayed-year)) (m (calendar-extract-month equinox)) (d (truncate (calendar-extract-day equinox)))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed m d 春分の日) '(7 20 1948))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 4 29 天皇誕生日) '(7 20 1948) '(2 17 1989)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 5 3 憲法記念日) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 5 5 こどもの日) '(7 20 1948)) (let* ((equinox (solar-equinoxes/solstices 2 displayed-year)) (m (calendar-extract-month equinox)) (d (truncate (calendar-extract-day equinox)))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed m d 秋分の日) '(7 20 1948))) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 11 3 文化の日) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 11 23 勤労感謝の日) '(7 20 1948)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 2 11 建国記念の日) '(6 25 1966)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 9 15 敬老の日) '(6 25 1966) '(1 1 2003)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 10 10 体育の日) '(6 25 1966) '(1 1 2000)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 4 29 みどりの日) '(2 17 1989) '(1 1 2007)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 12 23 天皇誕生日) '(2 17 1989) '(5 1 2019)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 20 海の日) '(1 1 1996) '(1 1 2003)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 1 1 2 成人の日) '(1 1 2000)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 10 1 2 体育の日) '(1 1 2000) '(1 1 2020)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 7 1 3 海の日) '(1 1 2003) '(1 1 2020)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 7 1 3 海の日) '(1 1 2022)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 9 1 3 敬老の日) '(1 1 2003)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 4 29 昭和の日) '(1 1 2007)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 5 4 みどりの日) '(1 1 2007)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 8 11 山の日) '(1 1 2016) '(1 1 2020)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 8 11 山の日) '(1 1 2022)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 2 23 天皇誕生日) '(5 1 2019)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 5 1 即位の日) '(12 14 2018) '(1 1 2020)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 10 22 即位礼正殿の儀) '(12 14 2018) '(1 1 2020)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 23 海の日) '(1 1 2020) '(1 1 2021)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 24 スポーツの日) '(1 1 2020) '(1 1 2021)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 8 10 山の日) '(1 1 2020) '(1 1 2021)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-float 10 1 2 スポーツの日) '(1 1 2022)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 22 海の日) '(1 1 2021) '(1 1 2022)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 7 23 スポーツの日) '(1 1 2021) '(1 1 2022)) (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 8 8 山の日) '(1 1 2021) '(1 1 2022))))) (holiday-filter-visible-calendar '(((4 10 1959) 明仁親王の結婚の儀) ((2 24 1989) 昭和天皇の大喪の礼) ((11 12 1990) 即位礼正殿の儀) ((6 9 1993) 徳仁親王の結婚の儀))))
Error: (invalid-function (japanese-holiday-range (holiday-fixed 1 3 元始祭) '(10 14 1873) '(7 20 1948)))
 Disable showing Disable logging
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((holiday-fixed 1 21 Dzień Babci) (holiday-fixed 1 22 Dzień Diadka) (holiday-fixed 2 22 Ofiarowanie Pańskie (Matki Boskiej Gromnicznej)) (holiday-fixed 2 8 Tłusty Czwartek) (holiday-fixed 2 10 Ostatnia Sobota Karnawału) (holiday-fixed 2 13 Ostatki) (holiday-fixed 3 1 Narodowy Dzień Pamięci Żołnierzy Wyklętych) (holiday-fixed 3 10 Dzień Mężczyzn) (holiday-fixed 3 20 Początek Astronomicznej Wiosny) (holiday-fixed 3 25 Zmiana czasu z zimowego na letni) (holiday-fixed 3 25 Niedziela Palmowa) (holiday-fixed 3 29 Wielki Czwartek) (holiday-fixed 3 30 Wielki Piątek) (holiday-fixed 3 31 Wielka Sobota) (holiday-fixed 4 2 (bank) Poniedziałek Wielkanocny) (holiday-fixed 4 8 Święto Bożego Miłosierdzia) (holiday-fixed 4 22 Międzynarodowy Dzień Ziemi) (holiday-fixed 5 1 (bank) Międzynarodowe Święto Pracy) (holiday-fixed 5 2 Dzień Flagi Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej) (holiday-fixed 5 3 (bank) Święto Konstytucji 3 Maja) (holiday-fixed 5 13 Wniebowstąpienie) (holiday-fixed 5 20 (bank) Zesłanie Ducha Świętego (Zielone Świątki)) (holiday-fixed 5 26 Dzień Matki) (holiday-fixed 5 31 (bank) Boże Ciało) (holiday-fixed 6 1 Międzynarodowy Dzień Dziecka) (holiday-fixed 6 21 Pierwszy Dzień Lata (najdłuższy dzień roku)) (holiday-fixed 6 23 Dzień Ojca) (holiday-fixed 8 1 Narodowy Dzień Pamięci Powstania Warszawskiego) (holiday-fixed 8 15 (bank) Święto Wojska Polskiego) (holiday-fixed 8 15 Wniebowzięcie Najświętrzej Maryi Panny) (holiday-fixed 8 31 Dzień Solidarności i Wolności) (holiday-fixed 9 23 Początek Astronomicznej Jesieni) (holiday-fixed 9 30 Dzień Chłopaka) (holiday-fixed 10 14 Dzień Nauczyciela (Dzień Edukacji Narodowej)) (holiday-fixed 10 28 Zmiana czasu z letniego na zimowy) (holiday-fixed 11 1 (bank) Wszystkich Świętych) (holiday-fixed 11 2 Dzień Zaduszny) (holiday-fixed 11 11 (bank) Narodowe Święto Niepodległości) (holiday-fixed 11 29 Andrzejki) (holiday-fixed 12 4 Barbórka (Dzień górnika, naftowca i gazownika)) (holiday-fixed 12 6 Dzień św. Mikołaja) (holiday-fixed 12 21 Początek Astronomicznej Zimy) (holiday-fixed 12 24 Wigilia Bożego Narodzenia) (holiday-fixed 12 25 (bank) Boże Narodzenie (1 dzień)) (holiday-fixed 12 26 (bank) Boże Narodzenie (2 dzień)))
Error: (invalid-function (holiday-fixed 1 21 Dzień Babci))
 Disable showing Disable logging
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((holiday-fixed 3 30 (bank) Good Friday) (holiday-fixed 4 10 (bank) Good Friday (England, Wales)) (holiday-fixed 4 13 (bank) Easter Monday (England, Wales)) (holiday-fixed 5 8 (bank) Early May bank holiday (England, Wales)) (holiday-fixed 5 7 (bank) Spring bank holiday (England, Wales)) (holiday-fixed 8 27 (bank) Spring bank holiday) (holiday-fixed 9 31 (bank) Summer bank holiday) (holiday-fixed 12 25 (bank) Christmas Day) (holiday-fixed 12 28 (bank) Boxing Day))
Error: (invalid-function (holiday-fixed 3 30 (bank) Good Friday))
 Disable showing Disable logging
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((holiday-fixed 1 1 New Year's Day) (holiday-fixed 2 14 Valentine's Day) (holiday-fixed 3 8 International Women's Day) (holiday-fixed 3 17 St. Patrick's Day) (holiday-fixed 4 1 April Fools' Day) (holiday-float 5 0 2 Mother's Day) (holiday-fixed 10 31 Halloween) (holiday-float 11 4 4 Thanksgiving))
Error: (invalid-function (holiday-fixed 1 1 New Year's Day))
 Disable showing Disable logging
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((holiday-easter-etc) (holiday-fixed 12 25 Christmas) (if calendar-christian-all-holidays-flag (append (holiday-fixed 1 6 Epiphany) (holiday-julian 12 25 Christmas (Julian calendar)) (holiday-greek-orthodox-easter) (holiday-fixed 8 15 Assumption) (holiday-advent 0 Advent))))
Error: (invalid-function (holiday-easter-etc))
 Disable showing Disable logging
Error (holidays): Bad holiday list item: ((solar-equinoxes-solstices) (holiday-sexp calendar-daylight-savings-starts (format Daylight Saving Time Begins %s (solar-time-string (/ calendar-daylight-savings-starts-time (float 60)) calendar-standard-time-zone-name))) (holiday-sexp calendar-daylight-savings-ends (format Daylight Saving Time Ends %s (solar-time-string (/ calendar-daylight-savings-ends-time (float 60)) calendar-daylight-time-zone-name))))
Error: (invalid-function (solar-equinoxes-solstices))
 Disable showing Disable logging
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this possibly be related to your having used a single quote that inhibits evaluation?:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html

Comment: Not really. `calendar-holidays` var expects sexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was sorted thanks to the amazing Emacs support.
The problem lies in the way `calendar-holidays` was set. The correct way should be:

```lisp
(setq calendar-holidays (append calendar-holidays
                        japanese-holidays
                        polish-holidays
                        english-holidays
                        general-holidays
                        holiday-christian-holidays
                        holiday-solar-holidays))
```